# NestJS subscriber hooks not getting called

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

My Subscriber Hooks like before*, after* are not getting triggered although my repositories store entities correctly into my database.

The only hook that gets triggered is the beforeTransaction. Am I missing something?

```js
@EventSubscriber()
export class TransferEventSubscriber
  implements EntitySubscriberInterface<TransferEvent>
{


  listenTo() {
    return TransferEvent;
  }

  beforeCreate(event: InsertEvent<TransferEvent>) {
    console.log(`BEFORE USER CREATED: `, event.entity);
  }

  afterUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<TransferEvent>) {
    console.log(`BEFORE USER CREATED: `, event.entity);
  }

  beforeInsert(event: InsertEvent<TransferEvent>) {
    console.log(`BEFORE USER INSERTED: `, event.entity);
  }

  afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<TransferEvent>) {
    console.log(`AFTER USER INSERTED: `, event.entity);
  }

  beforeTransactionStart(){
   console.log("this is working");
  }
}
```

```js
 const transferEvents = getRepository(TransferEvent).create(data);
      await getRepository(TransferEvent).save(transferEvents);
```

Comment: this isn't related to nestjs, btw. It is just TypeORM stuff

Comment: Thank you, very helpful

Comment: glad to help you out

Answer (score 0):

try providing this class in your module

```
@Module({
 providers: [TransferEventSubscriber]
})
```

if this doesn't work check your **typeormConfig** you should add the following line to it

```
subscribers: ['dist/**/*.subscriber{.ts,.js}'],
```